# I cannot access .htaccess on my web server

Tags: php, html, server, apache2

So, I set up a web server today on my raspberry pi, I have an index.html page setup and I want to have some links, linking to just root directories and listing them nicely, I downloaded the apaxy theme for apache2 and followed the steps to install and when i go to my web address /files/Images/.htaccess (im assuming this is what you are meant to do as I have no idea) it tell me "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /files/Images/.htaccess on this server."

Any idea? Please and Thank you

Comment: please explain your question briefly, by using which tool, you are trying to access file? no one can just enter example.com/.htaccess and view it.

Comment: honestly, dont really know what i am doing, might of though i was meant to just do example.com/.htaccess

Comment: I need to do more research but im being a bit lazy and having a rest break playing with my raspberry pi during exam study

Comment: You can edit .htaccess file by using tool filezilla or winscp for that you need to have ftp details.

Comment: well im directly editing it at the moment through ssh and an sftp connection

Comment: also an important point would be that this is a domain i bought that is redirecting to my ip address and tunneling through an external port to internal port 80. so when i enter the web address its actually example.me:808